# pip install -e is not resolved by python3

Tags: python, pip

everything was fine until December 2022 when packages installed in editable mode are not resolved anymore.

**reproducible example:**

from my terminal I run:

```
git clone git@github.com:pydata/numexpr.git
pip install -e --user numexpr
```

In my local folder, I find the following:

```
.local/
└── lib/
    └── python3.8/
        └── site-packages/
            ├── numexpr-2.8.5.dev1.dist-info/
            ├── __editable___numexpr_2_8_5_dev1_finder.py
            └── __editable___numexpr_2_8_5_dev1_finder.py
```

Now from a python interface notebook, I execute the following code:

```py
import numexpr
numexpr.__version__
```

which give me 2.7.1 which is not version I installed in editable mode.

But from the terminal, it returns the correct version.

```
$ pip show numexpr

Version: 2.8.5.dev1
```

Can someone explain why Python is not able to discover the lib? Is it related to the fact that there is no `numexpr/` in my `site-packages`?

**env:**
python: 3.8
pip: 22.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is coming from `setuptools`. They recently added support for [PEP 660](https://peps.python.org/pep-0660/) where the files are not copied to the site-packages folder anymore.

If this is not supported by your environment (yet?) setuptools offer some options to maintain the [legacy behaviors](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html#legacy-behavior):

```
pip install -e --config-settings editable_mode=compat numexpr
```